# C profiler for mingw

Tags: c, windows-7, mingw, profiler

I am looking for a good c profiler that supports multithreading in a mingw environment under windows 7. I mainly interested in the the CPU processing time. The processor I am using is AMD.

Comment: I have looked at few, valgrind, zoom, and oprfiler; if anyone can tell me which would be suitable for mingw in win 7 environment for C language.

Comment: Is it your goal to improve the program's performance, or do you simply want to do profiling? They're not the same. *[This method works in multi-thread programs.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)*